# Crystal Report not showing in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I added 2 new fields to my report data source SP. They are showing in report explorer as well as report preview.But not showing the newly added fields when view the  report in the browser. The  old fields are OK but  new fields shows as blank. 
 I am using CR 2010 ...

Please help

Comment: I am not use what the issue is but try restarting the browser and check.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?